# Munich transit visa for baggage collection for an Indian citizen

Tags: luggage, transit-visas

I am an indian studying in the US. Do I need to have a transit visa to collect my baggage at Munich airport?

Comment: Hi, please include your flight itinerary - right now my best guess is that you are travelling from India to the USA via Munich, but we don't know if those are direct flights, if you have additional plane changes etc.

Comment: If you need to collect your luggage in Munich you need more than a transit visa.  Please add all flight details including whether you have a self transfer

Comment: Do you actually know you will need to pick up your luggage (because the two flights are booked separately), or is it just a guess? If your two flights are in the same ticket then you don’t need to pick up your bags in Munich.

Answer (score 2):

If you are travelling from India to the US on an Indian passport, then you will be eligible for the airport transit visa only if you don't need to leave the airside zone. Since you need to pick up your baggage, you probably need to check your baggage in again and that needs to be done landside after immigration controls. In both cases you need to apply for either an airport transit visa (staying airside) or a tourist schengen visa (entering landside).

Comment: Luggage pickup is also after immigration check, not only check-in.